# How to compile the qtjambi examples

Tags: qt-jambi

I wanted to do something with qtjambi. I installed version 4.6.3. I can run the examples, but when I want to compile for example ArthurFrame, I get:
    ArthurFrame.java:47: package com.trolltech.qt.core does not exist

When searching for help, it looks everything is dead. The mailing-lists do not exist anymore and on #qtjambi there is no response. Should I just not start with qtjambi, or is there another place to get help?

Comment: By the way, I am using Linux. I sourced set_qtjambi_env.sh to set the environment variables and also set and exported LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: To see the error message:
    http://pastebin.com/YrfiQnqu

Comment: Found the solution. (In two parts.)  

    I was told that the beta was more stable as the stable version. ;-)

    So from http://unofficial.qt-jambi.org/ (only for Linux) I downloaded:
        qtjambi-linux32-4.7.4-beta-4-dist.tar.gz.

    I unpacked it with:
        tar -xzvf qtjambi-linux32-4.7.4-beta-4-dist.tar.gz.

    I ran the script 'install.sh'. The directory named has to be added to your CLASSPATH to be able to run programs that use qtjambi.

    But I also want to compile the programs. So I added also:
        qtjambi-4.7.4-beta-4.jar

Comment: When starting a prgram I always got (because I am using Xfce):  
        QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ theme.
  
I got rid of this by running qtconfig and selecting cleanlooks.  

But when trying to compile the program:  
        http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/qtjambi-tutorial1-code.html

I get:
    HelloWorld.java:16: non-static method exec() cannot be referenced from a     static context
            QApplication.exec();

Comment: Needed a little more. Also for one reason or another I do not get formatting to work. :-(  
.  
My first idea was to change:
        QApplication.exec();
to:
        QApplication.execStatic();

But that gives a segmentation fault when closing the program.

The solution was to change:
    QApplication.initialize(args);
to:
    final QApplication app    = new QApplication(args);

And to change:
    QApplication.exec();
to:
    app.exec();

Then the program behaves as it should.

With thanks to the people from the #qtjambi room at freenode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you obtained better support on the #qtjambi freenode IRC channel.  When using IRC for support you should be prepared to ask your question and wait for an answer, at least 12 months but sometimes a few days, during this time you should stay connected and "idling".

From there it was discovered you are using a Linux distribution that already has automated builds of a recent QtJambi available.

Ubuntu: https://launchpad.net/~qtjambi-community/+archive/libqtjambi-snapshots

- Instructions on the page for how to install.

openSuSE, SuSE, Fedora, RHEL, CentOS: https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?package=qtjambi-snapshots&project=home%3Adlmiles%3Aqtjambi-community

- Click on the link that is the name of the Liunux disto you are using (such as "openSuSE_12.2").
- Click on the link that says "Go to download repository".
- Click on the file *.repo to download and save on the local system.  Such as "home:dlmiles:qtjambi-community.repo"
- Install this file as 'root' into /etc/yup.repos.d/home:dlmiles:qtjambi-community.repo
- Edit the file to set the 'enabled=1' or manually add the --enablerepo=home:dlmiles:qtjambi-community when using yum to install.
- Run: `yum install --enablerepo=home:dlmiles:qtjambi-community qtjambi-snapshot-all`

These repos have been maintained over the past 18 months and should continue to be into the future whilst the respective distribution owners make them available in this way.

Once installed in this way you will get updates as and when they are published as part of your normal system package management.  So is has historically been about every 3 months.